# What is the meaning of "He's in the ticket"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "He's in the ticket" in the following pictures?

[image: Cartoon]

Comment: Surely, that's revealed in the rest of the comic, and the uncommon meaning of the word is supposed to build suspense, just like the identity of "he".

Comment: Just a wild guess: "ticket" is used in the sense of a collection of candidates running from the same political party for various offices during an election cycle.  It can also refer to the collection of scheduled acts at an entertainment event (not clear whether it is synonymous with the program, or refers to what is included in the price of the ticket).

Comment: Can you add a link to the source if you found this online? This really needs more context, but on the outside I wonder if it was supposed to be "He's in the thicket!" (related to some joke or a typo perhaps).

Comment: This is a sentence from Disney comic book, Bambi. When I googling, I can not search online-pdf book of the bambi, only Disney cartoon movies of the bambi are found on YouTube. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VztpFge0TKs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it refers to the collection of candidates (see [here](https://goo.gl/wXNrMd)). This would refer that 'he' is a candidate in the election, which is voted by ballot, or *ticket*.

Comment: There is no such "ticket" in the story of Bambi.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo of *thicket*.

Compare [this summary](http://www.cornel1801.com/disney/Bambi-1942/movie-film.html)  of the story Bambi:

> Story:
>
> A doe gives birth to a fawn in the thicket whom she names Bambi.

Surely the page in the comic book/graphic novel refers to the birth of Bambi. When a mother gives birth to a baby it's idiomatic to say 'the baby has arrived'.

The same source uses *thicket* two other times. From the same source it's clear that the thicket remained the place where Bambi lived:

> When Bambi arrives at their thicket, he discovers his mother is no longer with him. He wanders the forest calling for her, but she doesn't answer.

You can also find, all over the internet, references to *thicket* in relation to Bambi, including the title of blogs and quotes from the movie.